# Разница между экземпляром класса и экземпляром класса унаследованного от другого класса

Tags: ооп

В контексте объявления через `new` и `extends`:
в чем разница между экземпляром класса и экземпляром класса унаследованного от другого класса?

Comment: в чем разница между экземпляром класса и экземпляром класса унаследованного от другого класса?

Comment: Совсем непонятно, что именно ты спрашиваешь, какой хочешь получить ответ, и какая связь с `javascript` и `ruby`. Попробуй развернуть вопрос, возможно стоит добавить примеры

Comment: @АлександрСавчук, что интересно-то?

Comment: @АлександрСавчук, кто они?

Comment: @Grundy это всего лишь вопрос "чем автомобиль отличается от сварки кузова на автомобильном заводе?" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

new - используется непосредственно для создания экземпляра класса

extends - используется при описании класса для указание предка от которого он будет наследоваться

Comment: Это понятно, интересно просто что это значит "внутри".

Comment: экземпляр класс это непосредственно созданный в памяти объект с набором данных и все дела, а описание класса это просто код который описывает какой класс будет создан extends же просто наследует код другого класса в текущий .... почитайте основы ООП

Comment: простыми словами можно сказать так когда вы описываете класс то записываете на бумажку его структуру , типа у меня будет птица у неё будет клюв крылья и.т.д. дальше вы делаете extends  и описываете другой класс но наследуетесь от птицы , к примеру пусть это будет орёл, у орла тоже есть и крылья и клюв , + вы добавляете уникальное поле для орла .. такое как когти .... так вот это всего лишь описание .. у вас по факту нет орла ... вы лишь знаете какой он может быть. А вот new создаёт орла используя это описание

Comment: Теперь ясно, благодарю.